# Mouse disconnected after booting

Tags: usb, startup, mouse

Everytime I boot up my iMac (OS X 10.9.3) it doesn't find my mouse. If I unplug the mouse and reconnect it after around 20 seconds, it works.

It's an USB mouse. Every other USB device works fine.

I think this is the entry for the mouse:

> AND :
>
> Produkt-ID:  0x0001
>    Hersteller-ID:   0x13ee
>    Version:  0.10
>    Seriennummer:    @ɌAB
>    Geschwindigkeit: Bis zu 1,5 MBit/s
>    Hersteller:  MOON
>    Standort-ID: 0x24310000 / 5
>    Verfügbare Stromstärke (mA): 100
>    Erforderliche Stromstärke (mA):  100

My system language is german but I can change it, if you need this in english.

Comment: We need 2 pieces of information from you. Look up in the about this mac to see if mouse is detected. Second is your console log around the time when you plug the mouse in.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I think I've found the entry for the USB mouse, I will add it to the question. And how can I view the console log?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to download drivers for the mouse - I've found that personally, my RAT 7 works atrociously on OS X without the drivers and software for it.

It'd help to know what brand and model mouse you have, however generic it may be.

Comment: The mouse is a Speedlink Relic and I've looked for drivers, but I didn't find any drivers for OS X.